# Is this a good metaprogramming practice?

Tags: ruby

I wanted to make a simple DSL where I could pass a bunch of methods to a block, relying on self as the implicit receiver. So basically here you can call the 'say' method on this class object, passing it 'things to say' as methods in the block. The last line returns ['Maria']. I was wondering if this is a good programming practice for creating DSLs and if there are any problems with this approach.

```
class SaySomething
  def initialize
    @said = []
  end

  def hey(name)
    @said << name
  end

  def say(&block)
    instance_eval(&block)
  end
end

a = SaySomething.new
name = 'Maria'
a.say do
  hey(name)
end

a.instance_eval { p @said } #=> produces ['Maria']
```

Comment: It's neither good or bad. Just a common Ruby hack.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably add an `attr_accessor :said` and then replace your last line with

```
a.said
#=> ['Maria']
```

Other than that your code looks fine to me. If you want to learn more about metaprogramming in Ruby, I can recommend the book "Eloquent Ruby".

Comment: I agree, unless you don't want an accessor for some reason, in which case I would prefer `p a.instance_variable_get(:@said)` to the use of `instance_eval`.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem with this approach is that any class variables will collide with variables in the same scope as the block. The usual approach is to provide instance evaluation, but also allow the user to specify the class as an argument as a fall back.

```
class Test

  def test; "hello"; end

  def say(&b)
    if b.arity == 1
      b.call(self)
    else
      instance_eval &b
    end
  end
end


t = Test.new

test = "fred"

t.say { p test } # "fred"
t.say { |t| p t.test } # "hello"
```

Comment: Though I think later versions handle this with instance_eval already.